# History of Mathematics: Sophie Germain and Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Sophie Germain's greatest contribution to mathematics was in number theory. She discovered a special case of Fermat's Last Theorem which we now call the Germain Theorem.

Stated precisely:
The equation $x^p + y^p = z^p$ has no non-zero integer solutions where $p$ is a Germain prime ($p$ is a prime number if $2p+1$ is also prime) and $p$ does not divide $xyz$. Could someone prove this? I can't find an actual proof of this statement or Germain's surviving works in English translation.

Comment: This is proved in several books that treat Fermat's Last Theorem. But a really nice reference for this result (and much more) is Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen's beautuful book [A Classical Introduction To Modern Number Theory](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=jhAXHuP2y04C). There the theorem is proved in just about a page in Chapter 17, section 4, which is actually entitled "Sophie Germain's Theorem".

Comment: Thank you for the reference I will look for the book

Comment: The actual proof is given in the book's preview. Click the button and scroll down to page $275$. :)

Comment: Nonetheless, I recommend the book. It's a really, really nice book.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero Perhaps you could add your comment as an answer. See meta: [Dealing with answers in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I added an answer as promised.

Comment: See "``Voici ce que j'ai trouvé:'' Sophie Germain's grand plan to prove Fermat's last theorem" by Laubenbacher and Pengelley, as well as  "Unpublished manuscripts of Sophie Germain and a revaluation of her work on Fermat's last theorem" by A. del Centina.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sophie Germain's approach to the first case of Fermat's Last Theorem can be found in several textbooks that treat Fermat's Last Theorem. For example a very nice reference for her theorem is Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen's beautiful book [A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=jhAXHuP2y04C&pg=PA275). There the theorem is proved in just about a page in Chapter 17, section 4, which is actually entitled "Sophie Germain's Theorem".

To add something to my comment let me mention a generalization of Sophie Germain's theorem which was found by Ernst Wendt.

**Theorem (Wendt)**
Let $p$ be an odd prime. If there exists an integer $k \geq 1$ such that the number $q := kp + 1$ is also prime and satisfies

$$
q \not \mid (k^k - 1)\operatorname{Res}{(X^k - 1, (X + 1)^k - 1)}
$$

then the first case of Fermat's Last Theorem is true for the exponent $p$, that is, there are no solutions to $x^p + y^p = z^p$ with $p \not \mid xyz$.

Here the notation $\operatorname{Res}{(f, g)}$ stands for the [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the polynomials $f$ and $g$.

From this theorem we can obtain Sophie Germain's theorem as an inmediate corollary because in that case we are basically dealing with the case in which $k = 2$.

So we assume that $p$ is an odd prime such that $q = 2p + 1$ is also a prime number. Then we want to show that

$$
q \not \mid (2^2 - 1)\operatorname{Res}{(X^2 - 1, (X + 1)^2 - 1)}
$$

Now since $p > 2$ then $q > 5$ so certainly $q \not \mid (2^2 - 1)$. Also

$$
\operatorname{Res}{(X^2 - 1, (X + 1)^2 - 1)} =  \operatorname{Res}{(X^2 - 1, X^2 + 2X)} =
$$

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
= -3
$$

so $q \not \mid \operatorname{Res}{(X^2 - 1, (X + 1)^2 - 1)}$ either. Then by Wendt's theorem we can conclude that the first case of FLT is true for the prime $p$, and thus we have Sophie Germain's theorem as a corollary of Wendt's result.

**Note** A reference for this result is Henri Cohen's book [Number Theory Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=8zC8VPQV8psC&pg=PA430), it appears in section 6.9.4, page 430.
Also observe that I used the determinant of the [Sylvester matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) of the polynomials $X^2 - 1$ and $X^2 + 2X$ to compute their resultant.

Comment: I've added added page numbers to the Google Books links in your post - I guess this might be useful for some users. (Of course, I am aware that they will not be displayed to everyone.) I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for adding the page numbers. I didn't know how to do that so that's why I only linked to the front cover of the books.